# Updating a field item's value in a Sharepoint form via C# - value not displaying?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm having trouble with a field on my form displaying. It's a DateTime data type and is being used to track how many days an item has been at that stage of production. I tried converting the item.["DaysInInitation"] to an Int, to see if that would work but nothing displays still. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
                        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(URL);
                        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, password);
                        List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
                        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                        ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {
                            // important thing is, that here you must have the right type
                            // i.e. item["Modified"] is DateTime
                            //item["fieldName"] = newValue;
                            if (item.Id == fo.docid)
                            {
                                item.["DaysInInitation"] = fo.ini_di;
                                item.Update();
                            }
                            // do whatever changes you want

                            item.Update(); // important, rembeber changes
                        }
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // important, commit changes to the server
```

Comment: How's the `DaysInInitiation` field defined? What filed type is it? What's the type of `fo.ini_di`? You should also avoid the duplicate `item.Update()` call.

Comment: Insert    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); in foreach and try